# Trouble with Corona native.showWebPopup() for local file - file not found

Tags: coronasdk

I'm trying to organize some local html files and display them using native.showWebPopup() in my Corona app.  Testing on an Android device.

Right now if I put an html file directly in my main directory, I'm able to display it.

Example that works:

```
local options =
{
    baseUrl = system.ResourceDirectory 
}
native.showWebPopup("index.html",options )
```

However, I want to put the index.html file somewhere else.  For example, in a subfolder called foo.  But the app doesn't find it when I put it there.  I've tried a number of different things.

Some examples that don't work:

```
local path = system.pathForFile( "foo/index.html", system.ResourceDirectory )
native.showWebPopup(path)


local path = system.pathForFile( "foo/", system.ResourceDirectory ) 
local options =
{
    baseUrl = path
}
native.showWebPopup("index.html",options)
```

I've tried printing the path to the device log, but I'm not sure if it's what it should be or not...looks like this:
/data/data/(my app info)/files/coronaResources/foo/index.html

I can only assume that I'm pointing the app to the wrong place for the file, but I'm not sure how to fix it.  Thanks for any help on this.

Also, even in the example that works above, the HTML document loads, but the images are giving me trouble...even if I put them in the same main directory.  Is there something I need to do to fix that path?  This didn't work:
    <img border="0" src="./myimage.jpg" width="100" height="100">
and neither did this
    <img border="0" src="myimage.jpg" width="100" height="100">

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working for locating/opening the html files.

```
local doc = "foo/index.html"            
local options =
        {       
            baseUrl = system.ResourceDirectory
        }
native.showWebPopup( doc, options )
```